# Is it possible to make a complex ListView's divider?

Tags: android, listview, divider

Is it possible to make a divider drawable that consists of 3 images - 2 are ends of lines and the middle should stretch. So the idea is to make something like at any layout - to have ends with a fixed size - like wrap_content and the middle part is to be stretched.

Is it possible - to make it in xml drawable or programmatically?

Thx in advance

Comment: so you can use a 9patch Drawable

Comment: or you can use your custom Drawable and draw whatever you like

Comment: how's that possible? if I do it in xml-bitmap - it doesn't allow me to stretch something

Comment: or you can use your custom
Drawable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like pskink said, you can use an 9patch drawable as the divider. To convert your bitmap to a 9patch, use the [draw9patch utility](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)  in the tools directory in your Android SDK. Drag your bitmap into the draw9patch app window, then draw a black line on top of the stretchable area (on the topmost pixel line). Once done, save the bitmap as 9 patch (e.g. your_divider.9.png) and use it normally as a drawable for your ListView:

```
<ListView
    android:divider="@drawable/your_divider"
    ...
    />
```

More info on 9-patches available here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch